# How to specify a windows file path in a Go application?

Tags: windows, go, kubernetes, path, environment-variables

I am trying to specify the windows location for the .kube/config file for the Go client application without specifying the absolute path.

```golang
kubeconfig := flag.String("kubeconfig", "%USERPROFILE%/.kube/config", "location to the Kube config file")
```

Output :

```golang
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

When I use `echo %USERPROFILE%` in a cmd, the output is `C:\Users\<username>`, so I thought that this is because the different usage of `\` and `/` in the code and path.
I tried to specify the path using `\` instead of `/` but it gives out a syntax error.

Can anyone suggest me with a solution to use windows environmental variables to specify paths in a Go application?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The single line of Go you showed us will not panic. You need to show us a minimum reproducible test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `flag.String` itself does not expand environment variables but you can use `os.ExpandEnv` to do that. However `os.ExpandEnv` requires you to use the Unix notation for environment variables, i.e. `$USERPROFILE` or `${USERPROFILE}`. You can get a clean file path for our specific OS (Windows in your case) using `filepath.Clean`.

Example:

```golang
kubeconfig := flag.String("kubeconfig", "$USERPROFILE/.kube/config", "location to the Kube config file")
fmt.Println(*kubeconfig)
fmt.Println(os.ExpandEnv(*kubeconfig))
fmt.Println(filepath.Clean(os.ExpandEnv(*kubeconfig)))
```

This will output the following on Windows:

```
$USERPROFILE/.kube/config
C:\Users\username/.kube/config
C:\Users\username\.kube\config
```